# It takes time while exporting telerik grid to pdf

Tags: .net, telerik

I am trying to export telerik grid data to pdf/excel. Although telerik provides handy methods to export grid to pdf/excel but it takes lots of time to export the grid to desired format if there are more than 500 rows in the grid.

**Note: I want to export whole data but not visible page in the grid.**

Thanks
Anil.

Comment: Is the question "How can I export all the data to a pdf/excel?" or are you looking for something more in-depth?

Comment: Nope I would like to know "How can I export all the data to the pdf/excel without taking much time (reducing the time to export)?"....as of now if there are more then 500 rows then it takes much time and delays the process.

Answer (score 0):

The time needed to export this content depends strongly on your grid structure. You may be able to export 500 items or even 30000 items but to reiterate, it all depends on your setup. Post your markup here and I will look inside for you.